# why is fprintf() not writing to a file?

Tags: c

I am trying to get some text entered from the console written into a file called "output.txt" with the following code..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  printf("write something\n");
  char c;

  FILE *output=fopen("output.txt","w");

  if(!output)
    {
      printf("couldn't open file\n");
      return 1;
    }

  while(c=getchar())
    fprintf(output,"%c",c);

    fclose(output);

}
```

but the "output.txt" file contains no text when i open it. Why is this happening?
All help is highly appreciated .

Comment: So what happens? How do you think the loop will end? Are you looking in the output file before the program has ended?

Comment: You need to flush your output and have a proper exit condition in your loop

Comment: How do you terminate the loop? By pressing CTRL+C? This aborts the program probably before writing the buffered output to the file. Try `while((c=getchar()) != EOF)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you do not have a proper exit condition in your loop, the only way to terminate your program is by forcefully ending the process. This means that there is no guarantee that any pending buffered output will be written to the stream `output`.

What you can do is change your loop condition to `while((c = getchar()) != EOF)`. Then, you can use the characters <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (*nix) to make the loop condition false, reaching the line `fclose(output)`, which will flush the buffer and close the file.

Also, make `c` an `int`, since that's what `EOF` is.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like this:

```
  ...
  while ((c = getchar()) != 'X')
    fprintf(output, "%c", c);

  fclose(output);
  ...
```

Input:

ABCX<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Output.txt will contain `ABC`.